# How to store cookie value using Postman pre-request script?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

In postman, I have a pre-request scenario where I have to take a cookie value and store it in the environment variable, say *csrf* in my case, and use it for the API request. As shown in the image, I have 2 cookies for the domain namely XSRF-TOKEN and _d. I have to take only the *XSRF-TOKEN* for the particular domain and store it in *csrf* variable. I have to exclude *Path*, *Domain* and the *Secure* fields

My pre-request script:

```
pm.environment.set("csrf", pm.cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'))
```

[image: Postman_Screenshot_Cookie]

With this, the environment variable csrf is stored as null, and I don't understand where I have gone wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
const jar = pm.cookies.jar()

jar.get('example.com', 'cookieName', (err, cookie) => {
    console.log(cookie)
})
```

See:
https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/cookies/#get-a-cookie

You'll also need to whitelist the domain you're trying to get the cookie from:
https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/cookies/#whitelisting-domains-for-programmatic-access-of-cookies